# Boy makes clone of himself to stave off loneliness on a spaceship journey to his parents

Tags: short-stories, spaceship, clones, story-identification

The story is set in a space ship where a boy is traveling to his parents. To keep himself company he makes a clone of himself. For a while everything is perfect but then the kid starts feeling like the clone is stealing his life and he decides to get rid of the clone by throwing him out into space out of the garbage chute.

The entire story is written as journal entries by the boy and in the last entry we find out that he did successfully throw him out of the chute but its the clone who threw out the original kid.

I read this when I was 7, in 1999/2000.

It was in a collection of stories called *Stories for 7 year olds*.

Comment: So it's from [this book](http://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/f/fe/STRSFRSVNR1988.jpg)?

Comment: Or [this one](http://www.randomhouse.co.nz/books/various-authors/stories-for-7-year-olds-9781775536147.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It is not an exact match for "Bulkhead" by Theodore Sturgeon, but it has similarities.
Matches: It is set in a spaceship, and told in the first person. The narrator is an astronaut. He is having a dialogue with a young boy, who starts sniveling and crying. It is a long space voyage, and the space traveler can tolerate him no more, and does decide to kill him.

Differences: The space traveler is a grown man. He starts to cut through the bulkhead to kill the boy. His mission is cut short: a simulated mission to test his psychological fitness for the stress of long space travel. Surprise similarity: the boy is not another person, but his crying, fear, upset, and conversation are all actual amplified subvocalizing of the space captain, expressing his child fears and traumas. It is actually himself, not (another difference) a clone.

The similarities in this striking story got me to searching for it again after all these years.

Comment: Good answer and welcome to the site!  +1